# Typescript React.ReactElement vs JSX.Element

Tags: javascript, typescript

Basic Question:

What is the difference between the types `React.ReactElement` vs `JSX.Element`? Are they the same, when should I use each one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though JSX can be used in React to create React elements, React does not require JSX to work, you could replace it with vanilla JavaScript.

React elements are simply defined as a description of what you want to see on the screen. In other words, React elements are the instructions for how the browser DOM should be created.

A ReactElement is an object with a type and props. React reads these objects and uses them to construct the DOM. JSX.Element, on the other hand, is a ReactElement with generic type for props and type being any.

Comment: This is not entirely true. React works with abstract idea of what the elements (nodes) are. This allows for creating different renderers (like React Native which works with native UI components or ReactDOM which works with HTML DOM or even Ink which renders React Components in terminals).

Comment: What isn't entirely true?

Comment: @wirher (in case you're missing my question)

Comment: Your assumption that the person asking this question uses DOM at all.

Comment: Could you compare React Native with JSX? If yes, how?

Comment: Not really, JSX is not something that exists in compiled/transpiled react applications. This is just a syntax built on top of JavaScript for simplifying the declaration of component trees and is usually handled by Babel or TypeScript compiler. I wrote the first comment because this holds true not only for DOM but also for trees of components outside of a browser (e.g. React Native) and I felt like it is worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank you. Feel free to improve the answer. Something like «Even though React... to make sense at light of the comparison we focus on React DOM.». What do you say?